# python/numpy: vectorize nested for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, vectorization, nested-loops

I have been trying to shrug off my FORTRAN sensibilities over the last few days and embrace python's vecotrization to get rid of as many loops as possible and optimise my code.

A number of posts on this site have been incredibly useful in achieving this, but I have hit a problem I’m not sure how to solve.

Below is the "`for`-loop version" of the code which, I admit, uses some unnecessary array allocation, but it’s just to illustrate the issue:

```
mu       = np.zeros( nbk )
mubins   = np.linspace( -1, 1, nbk )
mu[:-1]  = ( mubins[:-1] + mubins[1:] ) / 2.

kbins    = 10**( np.linspace( kmin, kmax, nb ) )
k1       = np.zeros( nbk )
k1[:-1]  = ( kbins[:-1] + kbins[1:] ) / 2.0

nb       = 100
for i in range(         nb - 1 ):
    for j in range(     nb - 1 ):
        Bl = np.zeros( Nmodes )                 # ( will be important later ) initialising array here 
        for k in range( nb - 1 ):

            k33[i,j,k] = np.sqrt(  k1[i] * k1[i] + k1[j] * k1[j] - 2 * k1[i] * k1[j] * mu[k] )
            P11[i,j,k] = pkspline( k1[i] )      # just using intrep1d from earlier in the code - not important
            P22[i,j,k] = pkspline( k1[j] )
            P33[i,j,k] = pkspline( k33[i,j,k] )

            f212[i,j,k],s212[i,j,k] = S2F2_SLOW(k1[i],k1[j],k33[i,j,k]) # just calling some function - not important
            f213[i,j,k],s213[i,j,k] = S2F2_SLOW(k1[i],k33[i,j,k],k1[j])
            f223[i,j,k],s223[i,j,k] = S2F2_SLOW(k1[j],k33[i,j,k],k1[i])

             # computing B11 to be used in following ‘p’ loop
            B11=b1*b1*b1*P11[i,j,k]*P22[i,j,k]*2.*f212[i,j,k] + b1**2*b2*P11[i,j,k]*P22[i,j,k] + b1**2*bs2*P11[i,j,k]*P22[i,j,k]*s212[i,j,k] + b1*b1*b1*P11[i,j,k]*P33[i,j,k]*2.*f213[i,j,k] + b1**2*b2*P11[i,j,k]*P33[i,j,k] + b1**2*bs2*P11[i,j,k]*P33[i,j,k]*s213[i,j,k] + b1*b1*b1*P22[i,j,k]*P33[i,j,k]*2.*f223[i,j,k] + b1**2*b2*P22[i,j,k]*P33[i,j,k] + b1**2*bs2*P22[i,j,k]*P33[i,j,k]*s223[i,j,k]

            # new loop ( this is where my issue is ) v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v-v
            for p in range( Nmodes ):
                Bl[p] = Bl[p] + 2. * pi * LegMu[k,p] * dmu * B11
```

So thats the snippet of code. When vecotrizing this, it seems straight forward to remove the 
outer '**`i`**' and '**`j`**' for loops, leaving the inner '**`k`**' and '**`p`**' loops.

So below is my attempt to do this:

```
kbins = 10**(np.linspace(kmin,kmax,nb))
kk  = np.zeros(nbk)
kk[:-1]  = (kbins[:-1]+kbins[1:])/2.0

# so from above i now create 2 new arrays that will replace k1[i] and k1[j] in the previous version 
k1 = kk[np.newaxis].T #equivalent to k1[i]
k2 = kk               #equivalent to  k1[j]

#i and j loops now removed and left with k ( i may be able to get rid of the 'k' loop as well but i can't see how)
for k in range(nbk-1):
    k3[:-1,:-1,k]=   np.sqrt(np.square(k2[:-1]) + np.square(k1[:-1]) -2*k1[:-1]*k2[:-1]*mu[k])
    print k
    P1[:-1,:-1,k]=pkspline(k1[:-1])
    P2[:-1,:-1,k]=pkspline(k2[:-1])
    P3[:-1,:-1,k]=pkspline(k3[:-1,:-1,k])

    F2_12[:-1,:-1,k],S2_12[:-1,:-1,k]=S2F2(k1[:-1],k2[:-1],k3[:-1,:-1,k])
    F2_13[:-1,:-1,k],S2_13[:-1,:-1,k]=S2F2(k1[:-1],k3[:-1,:-1,k],k2[:-1])
    F2_23[:-1,:-1,k],S2_23[:-1,:-1,k]=S2F2(k2[:-1],k3[:-1,:-1,k],k1[:-1])

    #i've now put BB into a function. 
    B11[:-1,:-1,k] = BB(b1,b2,bs2,P1[:-1,:-1,k],P2[:-1,:-1,k],P3[:-1,:-1,k],S2_12[:-1,:-1,k],S2_13[:-1,:-1,k],S2_23[:-1,:-1,k],F2_12[:-1,:-1,k],F2_13[:-1,:-1,k],F2_23[:-1,:-1,k])
```

I took **`B`** array out of the **`k`** loop and just wrote:

```
B11 = BB( b1,b2,bs2,P1,P2,P3,S2_12,S2_13,S2_23,F2_12,F2_13,F2_23 )
```

**However,** the thing I can't seem to get my head around is how to follow on from this and incorporate the **`p`** loop as this is nested within the **`k`** loop:

```
for p in range( Nmodes ):
      Bl[p] = Bl[p] + 2. * pi * LegMu[k,p] * dmu * B11
```

**Crucially**, if you look at the first version I have to set **`Bl`** array to zero just before the **`k`** loop is called. There is stuff that happens after this, that uses **`Bl`**, but this is the place where I am stuck for now.

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

Ok, as requested I will simplify the above so it better illustrates the mechanics of the problem. You can ignore the array values I assign - its just an example:

So beginning with the "`for`-loop version" ...

```
kbins  = linspace( -1, 1, 100 ) )
mubins = linspace( -5, 5, 100 ) )

nb     = 100

BLB    = np.zeros( 10 )           # <--------------------------------- see q loop

for i in range(         nb - 1 ):
    k1 = ( kbins[i] + kbins[i+1] ) / 2.0

    for j in range(     nb - 1 ): 
        k2 = ( kbins[j] + kbins[j+1] ) / 2.0

        BL = np.zeros( 10 )      # <---------------------------------- see 'p' loop

        for k in range( nb - 1 ):
            mu = ( mubins[k] + mubins[k+1] ) / 2.
            k3 =  np.sqrt( k1 + k2 - 2 * mu )

            x = some_function(k1,k2,k3)
            y = some_function(k1,k3,k2)
            z = some_function(k2,k3,k1)

            B = x + y + z

            for p in range( 10 ):
                BL[p] = BL[p] + 2. * B

            for q in range( 10 ):
                BLB[q] = BLB[q] + BL[q]
```

so my attempt at vectorising this gets as far as the **`p`** loop to look like this:

```
kbins = linspace( -1, 1, 100 ) )                  # as before

# i now define k1 and k2 here as vectors, and not scalars as was above example
kk       = np.zeros( nbk )
kk[:-1]  = ( kbins[:-1] + kbins[1:] ) / 2.0

k1       = kk[np.newaxis].T                       # equivalent to k1 in above
k2       = kk                                     # equivalent to k2 in above

mu[:-1]  = ( mubins[:-1] + mubins[1:] ) /2.       # mu is now an array as well

for k in range( nbk - 1 ):                        # i,j-loops removed,left with k
    k3[:-1,:-1,k] = np.sqrt( k1[:-1] + k2[:-1] - 2 * mu[k] )     # k3 is now an array
    x[ :-1,:-1,k] = some_function(k1[:-1],k2[:-1],k3[:-1,:-1,k]) # x,y,z now arrays to allow looping over elements
    y[ :-1,:-1,k] = some_function(k1[:-1],k3[:-1,:-1,k],k2[:-1])
    z[ :-1,:-1,k] = some_function(k2[:-1],k3[:-1,:-1,k],k1[:-1])

    B11[:-1,:-1,k]= x[:-1,:-1,k] +  y[:-1,:-1,k] + z[:-1,:-1,k]
```

**but** how do i compute **`BL`** and **`BLB`** in the respective **`p`** and **`q`** loops?

I hope this makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Can you write a minimal example? This is fairly complex -- but if you were to write a minimal example that captures all the essential features of the problem you're trying to solve, it would be easier to help you. (And you might even find that you can solve the problem yourself.)

Comment: Will do. Just looking at it now thanks.

Comment: Ok so have added a stripped down version at the bottom of the original post. I hope this now a bit clearer. Thanks

Comment: In the for-loop version, should `Bl[p]` be `BL[p]`?

Comment: yip. well spotted. have updated. thanks

Comment: @russelljohnston Could you clarify your priority? Do you seek how to increase the code-execution speed ( a result ), or an understanding of the vectorisation ( as a method of code-design )? Also please confirm if the indentation levels of **`p`** & **`q`** loops is correct to be just a serial code-chunk inside the outer **`k`**-loop. Thanks

Comment: Could you give the numeric results for a simplified version, preferably with only a few items in each dimension (as few as 3-5), and simplified `sample_function`.  It's hard to compare a vectorized solution with an iterative one without a running example to test it on.

Comment: Sorry for delay... baby duties took over yesterday. I will post a numerical example as soon as I can. I should have done that already.  cheers

Comment: Also, to answer   user3666197, yes my main priority is to optimise. I thought vectorizing was the way to go and so then it became understanding vectorization.  The indentations for the **p** and **q** loops  are correct. That is, this is how they appear in the fortran version. Although I am looking at it now and thinking **q** can be brought inside **k**. Let me have a think. Either way, the **p** loop is definitely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `some_function` takes 3 scalars and returns a scalar.  `B` is also scalar.  So

```
        B = x + y + z

        for p in range( 10 ):
            BL[p] = BL[p] + 2. * B

        for q in range( 10 ):
            BLB[q] = BLB[q] + BL[q]
```

can be simplified to:

```
BL += 2*B
BLB += BL
```

I don't see the point iterating over `p` and `q`.  As written all 10 values of `BL` will be the same, as will the 10 values of `BLB`.

When I try to run your script (using a simple `some_function` like `k1+k2+k3`), I'm getting an intermitent error at `k3 =  np.sqrt( k1 + k2 - 2 * mu )`, probably because `k1+k2-2*mu` can become negative.  But ignoring that, I think your script simplifies to:

```
nb     = 11
kbins  = np.linspace( -1, 1, nb )
mubins = np.linspace( -5, 5, nb )

kx = (kbins[:-1]+kbins[1:])/2.0
kmx = (mubins[:-1]+mubins[1:])/2.0

for k1 in kx:
    BLB = 0
    for k2 in kx:
        BL = 0
        for mu in kmx:
            B = k1+k2-2*mu
            BL += 2*B
        BLB += BL
    print BLB
```

Here I played around with the nesting of the `BL` and `BLB` summations, so they made some sense.

If that inner scalar calc can be generalized to take 3D arrays, we can vectorize the whole thing.

```
k1 = kx[:, None, None]
k2 = kx[None, :, None]
mu = kmx[None, None,:]
B = 2*(k1 + k2 - 2*mu)
# (nb-1, nb-1, nb-1)
BL = np.sum(B, axis=2)
BLB = np.sum(BL, axis=1)
print BLB
```

Looking back the 1st script the `p` loop is a bit more complicated

```
for p in range( Nmodes ):
            Bl[p] += X[k,p] * B
```

which should work as  (assuming `X` is some sort of 2d coefficient array):

```
Bl += X[k,:] * B
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So just to clarify, the values I gave to **kbins** and **mubins** in my example were just made up for simplicity. I will clarify what **p** and **q** are _actually_ doing in at the bottom of my original post.